# Call javascript function from another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have a javascript file that reads the input from textbox inputs in MVC/AngularJS. The method looks like the following:

```
 $scope.Clients_CW = {
                ....
            }

function sendForm(data)
{
   $scope.Clients_CW = data; 
   var submitData = registrationService.SaveFormData($scope.Clients_CW);}
```

I'm using the jQuery wizard with next, previous and finish buttons. This is in a different javascript file to the code above. My finish button looks like the following:

```
$($this.buttons.finish).click(function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('buttonDisabled')){
            if ($.isFunction($this.options.onFinish))
            {
                var context = { fromStep: $this.curStepIdx + 1 };
                if (!$this.options.onFinish.call(this, $($this.steps), context))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else {
                var frm = $this.target.parents('form');
                if (frm && frm.length)
                {
                    alert($scope.Clients_CW);
                    frm.submit();
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
```

My question and problem is... how do I pass through the $scope.Clients_CW data to the finish button method or how do I call the `sendForm(data)` method and it's parameter in the finish button method?

Comment: Just load the js file that contains sendForm before the jsfile that needs to call it. Then you can just do sendForm(data); and it should work.

Comment: Store your $scope.Client_WS in a service / localstorage / window

Answer (score -1):

You can very well use route params to pass data between states. Refer [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service). You could also store the data in `$rootScope` or `$localStorage` for example to use the data in multiple states. The latter step would also work if both the files are required for the same state.